# How to put variable javascript as a style css attribute in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code right now is

```
const replace = (note) => {
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(
        note.replace(
            /\S/g,
            "<span class='letter' style='display: inline-block'>$&</span>"
        )
    )
};
```

as you can see in the span, I'm setting style as display inline-block directly. However instead, I want to set the style as some kind of variable like so:

```
const test = (note, style) => {
    const styles = {display: 'inline-block'};
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(
        note.replace(
            /\S/g,
            "<span class='letter' style={styles}>$&</span>"
        )
    )
};
```

but this isn't working because the `{styles}` inside the span doesn't know that I'm referring to my `styles` variable. Does anyone know the proper syntax to make this work?

Comment: `"<span class='letter' style='" + styles + "'>$&</span>"`. But, `styles` should be declared like this: `const styles = "display:inline-block;"`

Comment: or `\`<span class='letter' style=${styles}>$&</span>\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const test = (note, style) => {
    const styles = "display:inline-block;";
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(
        note.replace(
            /\S/g,
            "<span class='letter' style=" + styles + ">$&</span>"
        )
    )
};
```

You can do it this way or this way:

```
const test = (note, style) => {
    const styles = "display:inline-block;";
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(
        note.replace(
            /\S/g,
            `<span class='letter' style=${styles}>$&</span>`
        )
    )
};
```

Comment: `styles` needs to be declared as: `const styles = "display:inline-block;"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals:

```js
const test = (note, style) => {
    const styles = "display:inline-block;";
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(
        note.replace(
            /\S/g,
            `<span class='letter' style=${styles}>$&</span>`
        )
    )
};
```

MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: `styles` needs to be declared as: `const styles = "display:inline-block;"`